# BackboneJS 'click' event not firing when 'focusout' event exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a view in which I trigger dropdown that provides a number of options when a text input is in focus (similar idea to Select2) in BackboneJS:

```
events: {
   'click .option': 'clickItem',
   'focusin .big-select-input': 'focusIn',
   'focusout big-select-input': 'focusOut'
},

focusIn: function() {
   this.$el.find('.big-select-options').show();
},

focusOut: function() {
   this.$el.find('.big-select-options').hide();
},

clickItem: function() {
   console.log('item clicked');
}


<input type="text" class="big-select-input" />
<div class="big-select-options" style="display:none;">
<div class="option">Item</option>
<div class="option">Item</option>
<div class="option">Item</option>
<div class="option">Item</option>
</div>
```

What I have noticed, is that the click event for the option doesn't fire when the 'focusout' event exist. If I remove the focusout event (or blur event), the click works.

How can I get the click and focusout to both work at the same time?

Here is a barebones example http://jsbin.com/bivilujili/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: a working example could help understand what you are after

Comment: @Sag1v updated with a jsbin http://jsbin.com/bivilujili/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you think you're clicking an option but you're not. When you try to click an option the input has to lose focus. When input loses focus you're hiding the option's container. So you can't click it anymore. They just hide.

You need to update your logic to not hide them.

Comment: Well, i need both the focusout and the click to work. Example, if the user clicks anywhere else on the page, the big-select-options needs to hide. While when an option is clicked, it needs to do the same.

Comment: @David Then in the focus out, you need to make sure the element that is about to gain focus is not the options itself and prevent hiding it when it's about to gain focus. There are many browser quirks around this as far as I remember.